# replace symbols inside only one tag in php

Tags: php

I have a HTML string like this:

```
$text = "<strong>text</strong>more text<em>more text</em>additional text<span>text</span>....."
```

I would like to replace the `x` characters with `?` but only inside the `<em>` tag.

The string above will become:

```
$text = "<strong>text</strong>more text<em>more te?t</em>additional text<span>text</span>....."
```

How can it be done in PHP?

Comment: Regex would be the way to go with this kind of problem as a simple `str_replace` will not be aware of the context of being inside a tag only. This may be helpful: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20515/replace-words-between-tags-with-regular-expression

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I will have a look at the link you provide me

Comment: Regex is much more complex than reading the string with PHP DomDocument and iterating the corresponding tag to manipulate the text node using str_replace(). It is recommended to parse XML and HTML with the DomDocument class.

Comment: where can I find a tutorial on this ?

Comment: Hi! Sabrina and welcome to SO! Don't let some downvotes get to you. There are certain things expected from a post here. For example you did not show what you attempted so far. Also you might want to elaborate why you have a string like that. Maybe you can fix it before it's build in such a way and put it together.

Comment: Thanks Sven. I also studied at TUM in Munich. Anyway I have found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523887/replace-all-occurrences-inside-pattern

Comment: Should be reopend, because the question is focused enough for any PHP developer. It 's clear, that you have to use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` for a simple iteration and change of all found elements text content. I really don 't know, why this question needs to be more focused.

Comment: Although there is a working solution, there is a much simpler solution to this issue. After searching on SO you 'll get only thos RegEx bullshit answers, but not the real simple solution to such an issue.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the DOM extension. It's convoluted and documentation could use more examples, but it gets the job done:

```
$text = "<strong>text</strong>more text<em>more text</em>additional text<span>text</span>.....";

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($text);
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('em') as $em) {
    $em->nodeValue = strtr($em->nodeValue, 'x', '?');
}
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('body')[0]->childNodes as $node) {
    echo $document->saveHTML($node);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mgobo#v8.2.11)

Note my example assumes that you don't have other tags inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know it was also possible to do it in this way

Comment: Just load your html the following way: `$doc->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`. Furthermore PHP got its own XPath implementation. You can search for `<em>` elements that contain a `x` letter in its text node by `$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//em[contains(text(), "x")]');` If the result `$elements` is not false, you can iterate over all found elements and replace the letter in the text content: `$element->textContent = str_replace('x', '?', $element->textContent);`

After that just save the result with `($doc->saveHTML()`.

Comment: @Marcel I'd also recommend XPath.

Answer (score 0):

As Álvaro 's answer works out pretty well, there might be an easier solution using XPath.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Marcel;

use DOMDocument;
use DOMXPath;

$text = "<strong>text</strong>more text<em>more text</em>additional text<span>text</span>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//em[contains(text(), "x")]');

if ($elements !== false) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $element->textContent = str_replace('x', '?', $element->textContent);
    }
}

$text = $doc->saveHTML();
```

### What does the code snippet?

1. Load the HTML part with [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) and tell DOMDocument, that we don 't want to know anything about doctypes and dtd 's. That will be important when saving the manipulated HTML string. If not doing so, you 'll have an HTML doctype in the saved string.
2. Build an [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php) instance with the loaded HTML string / DOMDocument instance and query vor all `<em>` elements whose content contains the letter "x". The result of that will be either `null` or a DOMNodeList instance.
3. Iterate the [DOMNodeList](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domnodelist.php) instance if it is not null and replace the letter "x" with a question mark.
4. Save the manipulated DOMDocument back to a string. Since we told DOMDocument to not know anything about doctypes and dtd 's it is storing the loaded content only.

### The result

The result is a clean string with replaced "x" letters in the text nodes of `<em>` elements.

`<strong>text</strong>more text<em>more te?t</em>additional text<span>text</span>`

### Why using XPath instead of using RegEx

The answer is simple: Because it 's HTML. It 's recommended to parse and manipulate XML / HTML documents with PHP 's own DOM library because it 's way faster than using regular expressions and it is made for this kind of DOM actions. In the shown code example we 're using only one iteration. Even this iteration is pretty fast, because it 's using an internal iterator instead of a simple array. The difference is, that an [array occupies the memory exponentially](https://www.npopov.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html) with its entire content. An iterator only occupies the memory for the current element in the iteration. Long story short: More Performance. Less memory consumption.